# $_POST not working in PHP 7.2.0

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to send a form's data to a PHP function using POST method, but it's not working.I am using Apache and PHP v.7.2.0
This is my form:

```
<form  action="<?php echo $proc; ?>?function=edit" method="POST" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstName">
                    </div>                  
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" class="id">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="submit">Save</button>
                </form>
```

And this is my PHP function:

```
function edit() {
$connection = Database::getConnection();
$id = $_POST["id"];
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$query = "UPDATE person SET
            firstName = '{$firstName}',
            WHERE idPerson = {$id}";

if(!mysqli_query($connection, $query)){
    return 1;

}

return 0;
}
```

This is the Database class:

```
<?php

class Database {

    private static $db;
private $connection;

private function __construct() {
    $this->connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","my_db");
}

function __destruct() {
    $this->connection->close();
}

public static function getConnection() {
    if (self::$db == null) {
        self::$db = new Database();
    }
    return self::$db->connection;
}
}

?>
```

The weird thing is that I don't get any error messages.

Comment: what calls `edit()`

Comment: @smith That's not true. It will set `$_GET` values.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: since `action="<?php echo $proc; ?>?function=edit"` , the form data is going to be sent there to be processed

Comment: I can promise you that using `$_POST` works in the same way in PHP 7.2 as in previous versions. However, you seem to be using `$connection` inside a function even though I can't see it being defined or passed to the function at any point. I also don't see that the field `id` gets any value?

Comment: You should add phpinfo() to your script. It will reveal all your POST and GET variables along with a ton of other details.

That will show you what you are missing.

This reveals alot of private info so you definitely want to only use it for troubleshooting.

Comment: did you try to use an `input` tag for the submit button (instead of a `button` tag)?

Comment: @lonesomeday ha total misread that comcaternation there, thanks

Comment: the edit function is not called just  because the get value exists .. `if($_GET['function']=='edit'){edit();//edit function called}`

Comment: @Johannes - Why would that matter? The button tag even have `type="submit"` (which is the default for buttons anyway).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson `$connection` is defined as a global variable outside of the function, while the form input fields are filled with data via an ajax request

Comment: That's not how globals work.If you want to use `$connection` inside a function, you still need to import it using `global $connection;` inside the function (how ever, using `global` is bad practice), or you need to pass it to your function (`function edit($connection)` )

Comment: take a look at what magnus is saying here. you're not defining your connection in the edit function. Normally on this site a lot of people leave that out for succinctness but i have a feeling you may have posted the edit function exactly as it is. add global $connection to the top of that, and while you're at it, consider mysqli_prepare to escape those values.

Comment: @KaiQing but I have defined my connection in the edit function, I modified my question

Comment: Are you sure you can do that? Calling a static method needs to return statically. You're trying to return a non static private variable. Pretty sure `::` doesn't work that way but it's been a while since I've had to deal with static methods.

Comment: Also, have you tried just looking at the error logs? Do you have access to those?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder myself because db is static in theory a static method should be able to return that. Im no longer certain I remember things correctly on this.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion about what get parameters do unless you have some kind of internal handler that takes the $_GET['function'] value and calls a function of that same name. Don't do that if it is what you're doing.

if you left your form exactly as is, you can call edit in PHP by doing this:

```
if(isset($_GET['function']) && $_GET['function'] == 'edit')
{
    edit();
}
```

Additionally, your edit function is returning values. It's up to you to do something with those values...

```
$res = edit();
if($res){
    //do something
}
else
{
    // do something else
}
```

There are many ways to go about achieving what you're doing that are better, but for the sake of simplicity let's just say that placing "function=edit" in the url will not call a function of the same name. So much as I know, PHP has never behaved that way.

Comment: I have an internal handler that takes the $GET['function'] value and calls a function of that same name, is it wrong to do? Sorry for the late reply

Comment: so long as it's intentionally a public function and can in no way be exploited then I guess it wont hurt anything except your reputation if anyone ever audited the code. There's no sane reason to do it that way unless your code is so wildly inefficient it has thousands of functions and you don't want to write isset cases for all of them.

Comment: so, you're saying it is better to write isset cases for each function. I tried doing that, but the edit function still doesn't work

Comment: "better" is a matter of perspective. You can protect your code no matter how it is written. Just ideally you wouldn't take the long and odd way to handle common utilities. Without seeing your code I wouldn't know how logical your handlers are. As for your edit function - play with var_dump() and die(). kill the process in the middle to see if its even hitting the functions. Make sure your php errors are set to display, etc. Common debugging practice